# Remove background of an image and replace it with different color

Tags: image-processing, color, image

I have a picture that has a black background that is not entirely black, so I want to replace it with a totally black background. RemoveBackground works well in removing the background but I just want to replace it with another color. ColorReplace does not work well, since it will replace all the black pixels not only in the background.

Can anyone help me with that?

[image]

Comment: Just use `ImageCompose[]`: `ImageCompose[ConstantImage[Black, ImageDimensions[img]], RemoveBackground[img]]`

Comment: @J.M.: Interesting work around, thanks very much!